# loop while and look of the program in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am writing a program rock-paper-scissors and I have a problem with a loop while which I solved with another loop if but I still wonder why it doesn't work(line 19, 71, 104; or just in functions game, game2, game3). I also want to ask if I can write this program better or use something more advance to write it shorter. Here is the code:

```
import random
import time

option = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
your_score = 0
computer_score = 0

#functions  

def game(your_score, computer_score):
    print("ok, lets start")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(3)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(2)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    while your_score != 1 or computer_score != 1:
        if your_score == 2 or computer_score == 2:
            break
        user = int(input("What do you shoot?\n1.rock\n2.paper\n3.scissors\n"))
        computer = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
        show(user, computer)
        
        if user == computer:
            print("it's a tie\n")

        elif is_win(user, computer):
            print("you won\n")
            your_score += 1

        else:
            print("you lost\n")
            computer_score += 1
    
    if your_score == 1:
        print("You won, gg")

    elif computer_score == 1:
        print("You lost, nt")

def show(user, computer):
    if user == 1:
        print(f"You: {option[0]}")

    elif user == 2:
        print(f"You: {option[1]}")

    elif user == 3:
        print(f"You: {option[2]}")

    if computer == 1:
        print(f"Computer: {option[0]}")

    elif computer == 2:
        print(f"Computer: {option[1]}")

    elif computer == 3:
        print(f"Computer {option[2]}")
    
def game2(your_score, computer_score):
    print("ok, lets start")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(3)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(2)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    while your_score != 2 or computer_score != 2:
        if your_score == 2 or computer_score == 2:
            break
        user = int(input("What do you shoot?\n1.rock\n2.paper\n3.scissors\n"))
        computer = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
        show(user, computer)
        
        if user == computer:
            print("it's a tie\n")

        elif is_win(user, computer):
            print("you won\n")
            your_score += 1

        else:
            print("you lost\n")
            computer_score += 1
    
    if your_score == 2:
        print("You won, gg")

    elif computer_score == 2:
        print("You lost, nt")
        
def game3(your_score, computer_score):
    print("ok, lets start")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(3)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(2)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    while your_score != 3 or computer_score != 3:
        if your_score == 3 or computer_score == 3:
            break
        user = int(input("What do you shoot?\n1.rock\n2.paper\n3.scissors\n"))
        computer = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
        show(user, computer)
        
        if user == computer:
            print("it's a tie\n")

        elif is_win(user, computer):
            print("you won\n")
            your_score += 1

        else:
            print("you lost\n")
            computer_score += 1
    
    if your_score == 3:
        print("You won, gg")

    elif computer_score == 3:
        print("You lost, nt")
  

def is_win(user, computer):
    if (user == 1 and computer == 3) or (user == 2 and computer == 1) or (user == 3 and computer ==2):
        return True

def start():
    s = ()
    while s == "yes" or "no":
        s = str(input("Are you ready?'yes' or 'no'\n")).lower()

        if s == "yes":
            game(your_score, computer_score)
            break

        elif s == "no":
            print("ok, I'll wait")
            time.sleep(1)
            print(3)
            time.sleep(1)
            print(2)
            time.sleep(1)
            print(1)
            print("You should be ready now")
            time.sleep(1)
            game(your_score, computer_score)
            break

        else:
            print("wrong insert, try again")

def start2():
    s = ()
    while s == "yes" or "no":
        s = str(input("Are you ready?'yes' or 'no'\n")).lower()

        if s == "yes":
            game2(your_score, computer_score)
            break

        elif s == "no":
            print("ok, I'll wait")
            time.sleep(1)
            print(3)
            time.sleep(1)
            print(2)
            time.sleep(1)
            print(1)
            print("You should be ready now")
            time.sleep(1)
            game2(your_score, computer_score)
            break

        else:
            print("wrong insert, try again")

def start3():
    s = ()
    while s == "yes" or "no":
        s = str(input("Are you ready?'yes' or 'no'\n")).lower()

        if s == "yes":
            game3(your_score, computer_score)
            break

        elif s == "no":
            print("ok, I'll wait")
            time.sleep(1)
            print(3)
            time.sleep(1)
            print(2)
            time.sleep(1)
            print(1)
            print("You should be ready now")
            time.sleep(1)
            game3(your_score, computer_score)
            break

        else:
            print("wrong insert, try again")

def gamemode():
    g_m = 1
    while g_m == 1 or g_m == 2 or g_m == 3:
        print("1.The best of 1(up to 1 points)\n")
        print("2.The best of 3(up to 2 points)\n")
        print("3.The best of 5(up to 3 points)\n")
        try:    
            g_m = int(input("Which one you want to play?\n"))
            if g_m == 1:
                start()
                break

            elif g_m == 2:
                start2()
                break

            elif g_m == 3:
                start3()
                break

            else:
                print("wrong insert\n")
        except ValueError:
            print()
            print("wrong value, try again\n")

#actual program

gamemode()
```

I tried messing with the loop, but it didn't work in the end, so I just put in another loop inside. The loops while in my thoughts should work until these variables don't have a certain value but I might be wrong about it. The program itself might be looking weird and long in a run but it was on purpose to train using a `time.sleep`. Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Make your question more clear with a minimum code examples

Comment: Think about how *start()*, *start2()* and *start3()* could be re-written by passing appropriate parameters

Comment: This violates the coding principle DRY -- Don't Repeat Yourself. There is no reason to have essentially the same block of code 3 times in a row (in doing so twice). That is what loops and functions are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you are not making functions that are flexible enough to change. You should think about how you can re-use components to reduce repetition. On that note, you are also not making enough functions and repeating a lot of logic.

For example, to count down from a number you could write:

```
def print_countdown(count):
    while count > 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(count)
        count -= 1
```

Now that can be used everywhere you do a countdown.

For getting user inputs, you repeat your while loop logic a lot. This can be isolated into it's own method:

```
def user_choice(prompt, choices):
    while True:
        choice = input(prompt)
        if choice not in choices:
            print("Invalid choice try again...")
        else:
            return choice
```

With example:

```
choice = user_choice("Are you ready?'yes' or 'no'\n", ["yes", "no"])
```

Next, if instead of using an index to your options, you actually just used the string values themselves, your methods for printing options and testing a win become much simpler:

```
def show(user, computer):
    print(f"You: {user}")
    print(f"Computer: {computer}")


def is_win(user, computer):
    return (user, computer) in (
        ("rock", "scissors"), 
        ("paper", "rock"), 
        ("scissors", "paper"),
    )
```

For the main game method, have the target score of the user passed in, and check that for the win condition. This will allow you to remove the `gameN` methods. And you can re-use the helper methods you made.

```
def game(target_score):
    your_score = 0
    computer_score = 0

    print("ok, lets start")
    print_countdown(3)

    while your_score != target_score and computer_score != target_score:
        user = user_choice("What do you shoot?\nrock\npaper\nscissors\n", option)
        computer = random.choice(option)

        show(user, computer)

        if user == computer:
            print("it's a tie\n")
        elif is_win(user, computer):
            print("you won\n")
            your_score += 1
        else:
            print("you lost\n")
            computer_score += 1

    if your_score == target_score:
        print("You won, gg")
    else:
        print("You lost, nt")
```

Similarly this can be done for the other methods!

```
def start(target_score):
    choice = user_choice("Are you ready?'yes' or 'no'\n", ["yes", "no"])

    if choice == "no":
        print("ok, I'll wait")
        print_countdown(3)
        print("You should be ready now")

    game(target_score)


def gamemode():
    choice = user_choice(
        "1.The best of 1(up to 1 points)\n"
        "2.The best of 3(up to 2 points)\n"
        "3.The best of 5(up to 3 points)\n",
        ["1", "2", "3"]
    )
    if choice == "1":
        start(1)
    elif choice == "2":
        start(2)
    else:
        start(3)
```

Finally make sure to test that the application is being called as a script vs loaded as a module. This will allow you to use the game methods in other projects without accidentally starting the game by simply importing the module

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    gamemode()
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would do a rock paper scissors game:

```
import random

options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
your_score = 0
computer_score = 0
max_score = 3
playing = True

while playing:
    your_option = input(f"Options:\n - {options[0]}\n - {options[1]}\n - {options[2]}\nYour option: ")
    computer_option = random.choice(options)
    if your_option.lower() == 'rock':
        if computer_option == 'rock':
            print('Tie')
        elif computer_option == 'paper':
            print('Computer wins')
            computer_score += 1
        elif computer_option == 'scissors':
            print('You win')
            your_score += 1

    elif your_option.lower() == 'paper':
        if computer_option == 'rock':
            print('You win')
            your_score += 1
        elif computer_option == 'paper':
            print('Tie')
        elif computer_option == 'scissors':
            print('Computer wins')
            computer_score += 1

    elif your_option.lower() == 'scissors':
        if computer_option == 'rock':
            print('Computer wins')
            computer_score += 1
        elif computer_option == 'paper':
            print('You win')
            your_score += 1
        elif computer_option == 'scissors':
            print('Tie')

    else:
        print("Wrong input!")

    # Checking if score is max score
    if your_score >= max_score:
        print("You won the game")
        playing = False
    elif computer_score >= max_score:
        print("You lost the game")
        playing = False
```

If you want you can have a function called `main()` or `game()` which you will call at the very bottom of your code and that function should contain this while loop. IMPORTANT! Then you need to use `global` variable at the start so `your_score` and `computer_score` change values.